# Scrollable table with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

So I have table which gets filled using vue.js v-for method:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>
  <tr v-for="user in users"><td>@{{user.name}}</td><td>@{{user.surname}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

And I need this table to be maximum **`300px`** in height, and if it gets longer, it becomes scrollable.

So basically I need to set `max-height` and `overflow:auto` parameters in my css, but the problem is that the code does not "see" this table appropriately because it is rendered with vue.

So far I've tried just adding parameters in css and adding them dynamically after loading the table; none of these worked.

But, if I call `$('table').height()`, it returns the actual height of the rendered table. Maybe I can use it somehow?

Would highly appreciate any possible help!

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I recently published an open-source table wrapper component for Vue that does horizontal and vertical body scrolling.
https://github.com/richardtallent/vue-scrolling-table

Comment: @richardtallent sweet! great job!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you wrap the table in a `<div>`?

This way the div controls the scrolling and the table is free to go it's own way.

Comment: It works, but in this way the full table gets scrollable, I wanted headers to stay on top all the time

Comment: yup, it didn't work also. But I just figured it out and separated the head of the table into separate table and placed it outside the div.

Comment: yeah, your fiddle works this way, but with vue it would be ignored. so now my code looks like
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>
</table>
<div class="scrollable">
<table>
<tr v-for...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see why. This is the same code with vue: https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/e5nj8ebj/4/

Comment: well idk, didn't work for me. maybe the mistake was somewhere else

Comment: ok, but keep in mind that your code may be semantically wrong this way and thus less accessible and maintainable.

Comment: Having the same issue, the answer above is not a graceful approach. Only the tbody should scroll and the thead should remain aligned (which doesn't seem possible for some reason...)

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```js
"cssnano-preset-default": {
      "version": "4.0.7",
      ...
        "postcss-calc": "^7.0.1",
```

Wrap `<b-table` or `<table>` with `<template>` then `<div>` and add `css`

table.vue

```
<!--wrapper--->
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table
      <!--...--->
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "data-table",
  props: ["pageSource"],
  middleware: ["auth", "enable"],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["loggedInUser", "userSettings"]),
  }
  <!--...--->
}
</script



<!-- css at bottom of page -->
<style lang="scss" scoped>

.b-table {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
```